# Evaluating surface area

Tags: multivariable-calculus

These are two exercises from Apostol calculus that I am struggling to set up the integrals correctly. The biggest problem for me is finding the correct region $T$ under the surface $S$.

1. Compute the area of the region cut from the plane $x+y+z=a$ by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=a^2$.
2. Compute the area of that portion of the conical surface $x^2+y^2=z^2$ which lies above the $xy-plane$ and is cut off by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2ax$.

For problem 2, I set up the integral, but the computation is messy

Comment: I suggest using spherical coordinates transformation

Comment: For 1. no integral is needed: The plane $z=0$ intersects the cylinder in a circular disk of area $\pi a^2$. Now multiply this with ${1\over\cos\phi}=\sqrt{3}$, where $\phi$ is the angle between the planes $z=0$ and $x+y+z=a$.

Comment: I understand that it is meant to be done by integration, but no. 1 can be done by pretty simple geometry. the required surface is an ellipse with semimajor axis $\sqrt{3}a$, semiminor axis $a$. Thus the area is $\pi\sqrt{3}a\times a$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if we parametrise a surface $T$ by two parameters $(u, v)$ then the area of the surface is given by $Area(T) = \int\int\|T_u \times T_v\|dudv $. For more details see [this pdf](http://math.ucsd.edu/%7Elni/math20e/l16.pdf).

---

For part(a),
We have to compute the area cut out from the plane $x+y+z = a$ by the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$, so parametrise the surface as follows. The variable u represents the radius of the cylinder, and $\theta$ the angle with respect to the xy-plane and our given plane.

$$r(u, \theta) = u\cos\theta \hat{i} + u\sin\theta \hat{j} + (a - u\cos\theta - u\sin\theta)\hat{k}$$

Now we calculate the partial derivatives.
$$r_u = cos\theta \hat{i} + sin\theta\hat{j} - (cos\theta + sin\theta)\hat{k}$$

$$r_{\theta} = -u\sin\theta\hat{i} + u\cos\theta\hat{j} + (u\sin\theta - u\cos\theta)\hat{k}$$

$$r_u\times r_\theta = u\hat{i} + u\hat{j} + u\hat{k}$$
$$\implies\|r_u\times r_\theta\| = \sqrt{3}u$$

Hence the area of the surface is given by
$$\int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi}\int_{u = 0}^{a}\sqrt{3}ududv = \sqrt{3}\pi a^2$$

---

For part(b), we repeat the same procedure. First parametrise the surface (cone),

$$r(u, \theta) = u\cos\theta \hat{i} + u\sin\theta \hat{j} + u\hat{k}$$

$$r_u = \cos\theta\hat{i} + \sin\theta\hat{j} + \hat{k}$$
$$r_\theta = -u\sin\theta\hat{i} + u\cos\theta\hat{j}$$

$$\implies\|r_u\times r_\theta\| = \sqrt2u$$

To find the area cutoff by the sphere,
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2ax$$
$$\implies 2z^2 \leq 2ax $$
$$\implies u \leq a\cos\theta$$

The sphere is moved by a unit radius on the x axis i.e the origin is on the boundary of the sphere.

Hence we only integrate $\theta$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.
The required area is,
$$\int_{\theta = -\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{u = 0}^{a\cos\theta} \sqrt2 u dud\theta = \frac{\pi a^2}{2\sqrt{2}}$$